# How to run Selenium WebDriver on a docker container and use it on Airflow?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, airflow, selenium-docker

I am trying to run webdriver on a docker container without success. Docker is running on a Windows machine.

Below is the simple DAG that I am using.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromiumService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType

     


with DAG(
    dag_id='webdriver_testv01',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 5, 5),
    schedule_interval='@once',
    catchup=False
) as dag:
    pass

def webdriver_import():


    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromiumService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()))
    driver.get("http://www.python.org")
    result = driver.title
    return result

with DAG(
    dag_id='webdriver_testv01',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 5, 5),
    schedule_interval='@once',
    catchup=False
) as dag:

    
    webdriverget = PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'get_the_webdriver',
        python_callable = webdriver_import
    )
```

Which fails due to the following error:

> ```
> 16c031c5e336
> *** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=webdriver_testv01/run_id=manual__2023-01-22T17:32:08.683565+00:00/task_id=get_the_webdriver/attempt=1.log
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1087} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: webdriver_testv01.get_the_webdriver manual__2023-01-22T17:32:08.683565+00:00 [queued]>
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1087} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: webdriver_testv01.get_the_webdriver manual__2023-01-22T17:32:08.683565+00:00 [queued]>
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1283} INFO - 
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1284} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1285} INFO - 
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1304} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): get_the_webdriver> on 2023-01-22 17:32:08.683565+00:00
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:55} INFO - Started process 2428 to run task
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'webdriver_testv01', 'get_the_webdriver', 'manual__2023-01-22T17:32:08.683565+00:00', '--job-id', '429', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/get_the_webdriver.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp_894a7u9']
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 429: Subtask get_the_webdriver
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {task_command.py:389} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: webdriver_testv01.get_the_webdriver manual__2023-01-22T17:32:08.683565+00:00 [running]> on host 16c031c5e336
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1513} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=webdriver_testv01
> AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=get_the_webdriver
> AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-01-22T17:32:08.683565+00:00
> AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
> AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-01-22T17:32:08.683565+00:00
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {logger.py:11} INFO - ====== WebDriver manager ======
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {logger.py:11} INFO - Get LATEST chromedriver version for chromium None
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {logger.py:11} INFO - There is no [linux64] chromedriver for browser None in cache
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {logger.py:11} INFO - About to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/109.0.5414.74/chromedriver_linux64.zip
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading:   0%|          | 0.00/6.96M [00:00<?, ?B/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:11 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading:   9%|9         | 672k/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 6.86MB/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading:  19%|#8        | 1.31M/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 6.86MB/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading:  30%|##9       | 2.07M/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 7.35MB/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading:  41%|####1     | 2.87M/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 7.72MB/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading:  52%|#####1    | 3.61M/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 7.62MB/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading:  62%|######2   | 4.34M/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 7.34MB/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading:  72%|#######2  | 5.05M/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 7.29MB/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading:  83%|########2 | 5.75M/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 7.30MB/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading:  94%|#########3| 6.52M/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 7.53MB/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} WARNING - 
> [WDM] - Downloading: 100%|##########| 6.96M/6.96M [00:00<00:00, 7.42MB/s]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:13 UTC] {logger.py:11} INFO - Driver has been saved in cache [/home/***/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/109.0.5414]
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1772} ERROR - Task failed with exception
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 175, in execute
>     return_value = self.execute_callable()
>   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 192, in execute_callable
>     return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
>   File "/opt/airflow/dags/get_the_webdriver.py", line 26, in webdriver_import
>     driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromiumService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()))
>   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 90, in __init__
>     keep_alive,
>   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 103, in __init__
>     self.service.start()
>   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 105, in start
>     self.assert_process_still_running()
>   File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 118, in assert_process_still_running
>     raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self.path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/airflow/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/109.0.5414/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
>
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1327} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=webdriver_testv01, task_id=get_the_webdriver, execution_date=20230122T173208, start_date=20230122T173211, end_date=20230122T173213
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:13 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:105} ERROR - Failed to execute job 429 for task get_the_webdriver (Message: Service /home/airflow/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/109.0.5414/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
> ; 2428)
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:13 UTC] {local_task_job.py:159} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
> [2023-01-22, 17:32:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2582} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
> ```

My requirements.txt file is:

```
scikit-learn==0.24.2
selenium==4.7.0
webdriver_manager==3.8.5
chromedriver-autoinstaller==0.4.0
```

And my Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.0
USER airflow
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --user --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r /requirements.txt
```

And my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
# or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
# distributed with this work for additional information
# regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
# to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
# "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
# with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
# software distributed under the License is distributed on an
# "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
# KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations
# under the License.
#

# Basic Airflow cluster configuration for CeleryExecutor with Redis and PostgreSQL.
#
# WARNING: This configuration is for local development. Do not use it in a production deployment.
#
# This configuration supports basic configuration using environment variables or an .env file
# The following variables are supported:
#
# AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME           - Docker image name used to run Airflow.
#                                Default: apache/airflow:2.5.0
# AIRFLOW_UID                  - User ID in Airflow containers
#                                Default: 50000
# Those configurations are useful mostly in case of standalone testing/running Airflow in test/try-out mode
#
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME   - Username for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD   - Password for the administrator account (if requested).
#                                Default: airflow
# _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS - Additional PIP requirements to add when starting all containers.
#                                Default: ''
#
# Feel free to modify this file to suit your needs.
---
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  #image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-extending_airflow:latest}
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    expose:
      - 6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 9099:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      # Required to handle warm shutdown of the celery workers properly
      # See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/entrypoint.html#signal-propagation
      DUMB_INIT_SETSID: "0"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-triggerer:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: triggerer
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type TriggererJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - |
        function ver() {
          printf "%04d%04d%04d%04d" $${1//./ }
        }
        airflow_version=$$(AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO && gosu airflow airflow version)
        airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${airflow_version})
        min_airflow_version=2.2.0
        min_airflow_version_comparable=$$(ver $${min_airflow_version})
        if (( airflow_version_comparable < min_airflow_version_comparable )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;31mERROR!!!: Too old Airflow version $${airflow_version}!\e[0m"
          echo "The minimum Airflow version supported: $${min_airflow_version}. Only use this or higher!"
          echo
          exit 1
        fi
        if [[ -z "${AIRFLOW_UID}" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: AIRFLOW_UID not set!\e[0m"
          echo "If you are on Linux, you SHOULD follow the instructions below to set "
          echo "AIRFLOW_UID environment variable, otherwise files will be owned by root."
          echo "For other operating systems you can get rid of the warning with manually created .env file:"
          echo "    See: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#setting-the-right-airflow-user"
          echo
        fi
        one_meg=1048576
        mem_available=$$(($$(getconf _PHYS_PAGES) * $$(getconf PAGE_SIZE) / one_meg))
        cpus_available=$$(grep -cE 'cpu[0-9]+' /proc/stat)
        disk_available=$$(df / | tail -1 | awk '{print $$4}')
        warning_resources="false"
        if (( mem_available < 4000 )) ; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough memory available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 4GB of memory required. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((mem_available * one_meg)))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( cpus_available < 2 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough CPUS available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 2 CPUs recommended. You have $${cpus_available}"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if (( disk_available < one_meg * 10 )); then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: Not enough Disk space available for Docker.\e[0m"
          echo "At least 10 GBs recommended. You have $$(numfmt --to iec $$((disk_available * 1024 )))"
          echo
          warning_resources="true"
        fi
        if [[ $${warning_resources} == "true" ]]; then
          echo
          echo -e "\033[1;33mWARNING!!!: You have not enough resources to run Airflow (see above)!\e[0m"
          echo "Please follow the instructions to increase amount of resources available:"
          echo "   https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html#before-you-begin"
          echo
        fi
        mkdir -p /sources/logs /sources/dags /sources/plugins
        chown -R "${AIRFLOW_UID}:0" /sources/{logs,dags,plugins}
        exec /entrypoint airflow version
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - .:/sources

  airflow-cli:
    <<: *airflow-common
    profiles:
      - debug
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      CONNECTION_CHECK_MAX_COUNT: "0"
    # Workaround for entrypoint issue. See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16252
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - airflow

  # You can enable flower by adding "--profile flower" option e.g. docker-compose --profile flower up
  # or by explicitly targeted on the command line e.g. docker-compose up flower.
  # See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/
  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    profiles:
      - flower
    ports:
      - 5559:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. I have tried all the different browser options listed on https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/ without success.

Could be that the webdriver needs an executable path to run? I'm not sure how to do that either since this is a docker container.